Sending a key to a different application?
I want to send keys to a different application. In the current version of my code it tries to bring the application to the forefront, but it doesn't. In fact, it should not bring it to the front it should work automatically when the application is in the background.
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace macro
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        const int VK_SPACE = 0x20;
        private Thread autoPressThread;
        private bool isPressing = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            this.MaximumSize = new Size(320, 240);
            this.MinimumSize = new Size(320, 240);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void StartKeyPressing(string windowName)
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, windowName);
            if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Application not found!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            while (isPressing)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
                       
                if (GetForegroundWindow() == hWnd)
                {
                    keybd_event(VK_SPACE, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
                }
                else
                {
                    keybd_event(VK_SPACE, 0, 2, UIntPtr.Zero);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            keybd_event(VK_SPACE, 0, 2, UIntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = textBox1.Text;
            string windowName = "Sezar2 - " + name;

            isPressing = true;
            autoPressThread = new Thread(() => StartKeyPressing(windowName));
            autoPressThread.IsBackground = true;
            autoPressThread.Start();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isPressing = false;
            if (autoPressThread != null && autoPressThread.IsAlive)
            {
                autoPressThread.Join();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Space tuşu bırakıldı.", "Bilgi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}


I edited your question. I'm not sure how this is supposed to work, if you try and send keys its the active application that receives them, you can't send keys to a application in the background. You'll need to bring it to the Front:  SetForegroundWindow(handle);  SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE); then set it back: SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

This question is similar to: Send Keystrokes to a program even if its in background using c#. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found through using a site search, where Sendkey to background program was closed as a duplicate of this.
